# About adding strict unity to bicategories and the strictification functor

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

I use the terminology of https://ncatlab.org and:

[CT] Coherence for tricategories -  R. Gordon, A. J. Power, Ross Street .

[EK] Closed Categories -     Samuel EilenbergG. Max Kelly .

***Strict unity***
I say that a bicategory $\mathscr{C}$ has the ***strict unity*** if the unitary morphisms  $I_X: X\to X$ have the proprieties:
$I_Y\circ f=f= f\circ I_X\ for\ f:X\to Y$ and  $r_{f}=\ell_{f}=1_{f}$, $a_{I, g, f}=a_{g, I, f}=a_{g, f, I}=1_{g\circ f}$. Given a bicategory $\mathscr{C}$
we can make  $\mathscr{C}_{(1)}$  with strict unity adding to $\mathscr{C}$ the  (new) strict unities $1_X: X\to X$ (with identity cells $1_{1_X}: 1_X\to 1_X$) different from the usual $I_X: X\to X$,  with new isomorphisms $u_x: I_X\to 1_X$ and  $a_{1, g, f}=a_{g, 1, f}=a_{g, f, 1}:=1_{g\circ f}$,  and define $f\circ u_X:= r_f,\ u_Y\circ f:= \ell_f$.
This define  a inclusion $\iota: \mathscr{C}\subset \mathscr{C}_{(1)}$ that fix objets, morphisms, cells, this is a pseudo-functor with $\iota:{g, f}=1_{g\circ f}$,  $\iota_X:=u_X: I_X \to 1_X $, with a pseudo-functor $j: \mathscr{C}_{(1)}\to\mathscr{C}$ with $j\circ \iota=1$, $j_{1, f}= \ell_f^{-1}: f\to I_Y\circ f,\ j_{f, 1}= r_f^{-1}: f\to f\circ I_X$,  $j(1_X)=I_X$ and $j_X:=1_{I_X}: I_X \to I_X$, $j(u_X)=1$.

Let $|2-CAt|$ the (meta)category of 2-categories and 2-functors, $|HBIcat|$ the (meta)category of bicategories and pseudo.functors,
From [CT] (pag.36-39) the (full) inclusion functor $J: |2-CAt| \subset  |HBIcat|$ has a left-adjoint $st$ (the strictification), and is defined a cubic funtors (see [CT] pag.31)

$$\widehat{st}_{\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}}: st(\mathcal{A})\times st(\mathcal{B})\to st(\mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{B})$$

that define a monoidal functor from the cartesian-monoidal categories $|HBIcat|$ to $|2-CAt|$, its right adjoint $J$ is strict monoidal.

In [CT] the proof that  $\widehat{st}_{\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}}$ is a cubic functor is a bit tedious, I found a more easy and direct way:

Let $HBIcat_{(1)}$ the (meta)category of bicategories with strict-unity and normal pseudo-functors (normal mean that are unity-preserving),
define  $st_1: |HBIcat_{(1)}| \to |2-Cat|$ where $st_1(\mathcal{C})$ and $\mathcal{C}$ has the some objects and unitary morphisms, and the non unitary morphisms of $st_1(\mathcal{C})$ are sequences of non-unitary (componible) morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$, the composition of
non unitary morphisms is for concatenation. Given a bicategory $\mathcal{C}$ we can write
$$st(\mathcal{C})=st_1(\mathcal{C}_{(1)})$$ where identifying the empty string with the strict unity of $\mathcal{C}_{(1)}$.

We have the  endo-functor $$st_1: |HBIcat_{(1)}|\to |HBIcat_{(1)}|$$ such $st_1$ don't send ever pseudo-functors on 2-functors (as $st$ does instead) as in the example:

Given the bicategories $\mathcal{A},\ \mathcal{B}$ we have the normal pseudo-funtor $\partial: \mathcal{A}_{(1)}\times \mathcal{B}_{(1)}\to (\mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{B})_{(1)}$ that fix $\mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{B}$ and with $\partial(f, 1_B) =(f, I_B),\ \partial(1_A, g) =(I_A, g)$ then  $st_1(\partial): st_1(\mathcal{A}_{(1)}\times \mathcal{B}_{(1)})\to
st_1((\mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{B})_{(1)})$ is a normal pseudo.functor but no a  2-functor.

Anyway  we have the 2-functor
$$\wp: st_1(\mathcal{A}_{(1)})\times st_1(\mathcal{B}_{(1)})\to
st_1(\mathcal{A}_{(1)}\times \mathcal{B}_{(1)})$$

with $\wp((f_n,\ldots,f_1),\ (g_m,\ldots,g_1))=(1, g_m)\ldots,(1, g_1), (f_n, 1)\ldots, (f_1,1))$. The composition
$$st(\mathcal{A})\times st(\mathcal{B})=
st_1(\mathcal{A}_{(1)})\times st_1(\mathcal{B}_{(1)}) \xrightarrow{\wp}
st_1(\mathcal{A}_{(1)}\times \mathcal{B}_{(1)}) \xrightarrow{st_1(\partial)}
st_1((\mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{B})_{(1)}) =
st(\mathcal{A}\times \mathcal{B})$$ is then a  normal pseudo.funtor, and its nudging (see [CT] p.34) is the cubic-funtor :
$\widehat{st}_{\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}}$ of [CT].

***Fist question***: are these constructions (as $\mathscr{C}_{(1)}$) just knew in literature?

Is natural extend  $st$ to lax.transformations (and similarly on modifications), given $\alpha: F\Rightarrow G: \mathcal{A}\to \mathcal{C}$,  define $st(\alpha): st(F)\Rightarrow st(G): st(\mathcal{A})\to st(\mathcal{C})$ as $st(\alpha)_A=(\alpha_A)\ A\in \mathcal{A}$ and for $\underline{f}=(f_n,\ldots, f_1)\in st(\mathcal{A})(A, B)\ f_i: A_{i-1}\to A_i\ i=1,\ldots n,\ A_0=A, A_n=B$ let

$$st(\alpha)_{\underline{f}}: [st(G)(\underline{f})\circ (\alpha_A)]  \cong
G(f_n)\circ \ldots\circ G(f_2)\circ [G(f_1)\circ \alpha_A] \xrightarrow{1\alpha_{f_1}}
G(f_n)\circ \ldots\circ [G(f_2)\circ \alpha_{A_1}]\circ F(f_1) \xrightarrow{1\alpha_{f_2}1} $$

$$G(f_n)\circ \ldots\circ [\alpha_{A_2}\circ F(f_2)]\circ F(f_1) \xrightarrow{1\alpha_{f_2}1} \ldots
 \xrightarrow{\alpha_{f_n}1} \alpha_B\circ F(f_n)\circ \ldots\circ F(f_1)\cong [(\alpha_B)\circ F(\underline{f})]$$

Considering 2-categories 2-functors, pseudo-transformation (for simplicity) and modification we have the $(|2-CAt|, \otimes , 1)$-enriched category $2-CAT_{lax}$, where $\otimes$ is the Gray-product (in the form given in [CT].)

***Question***: Is the Gray product extendible also on bicategories?

If so, considering bicategories pseudo-functors, lax-transformation and modification we have the $(|HBIcat|, \otimes, 1)$-enriched category $HBIcat_{lax}$.

***Question***: Are $st$ and $J$ monoidal functors respect the Gray-monoidal product?

If so, from the (strict)monoidal  $J: (|2-CAt|, \otimes , 1)\to (|HBIcat|, \otimes , 1)$ follow  the
$(|HBIcat|, \otimes, 1)$-enriched category $J_\ast(2-CAt_{lax})$ (sse [EK] prop.6.3 pag 497).

I claim that $st: HBIcat_{lax}\to J_\ast(2-CAT_{lax})$ is a $(|HBIcat|, \otimes, 1)$-enriched-functor.

***question***: are my claim true?

Comment: You may be interested in my paper [How strict is strictification?](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jpaa.2018.10.004), in which I treat strictification of bicategories as a morphism of multicategories.

Comment: Campbell Alexander. Yes, I find your paper just  after wrote my post, seem very general, I'll see if my claims follow as corollaries. Thank you.